# ASP "Operation not Allowed" error occured while eecute Request.Form method

Tags: asp-classic

I have run the following script for increase the file size for upload
       E:\inetpub\adminscripts
       cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/ASPMaxRequestEntityAllowed size

After running the command.I am getting this error...

Request object error 'ASP 0104 : 80004005'

Operation not Allowed

/ewqms370/common/indexintermediate.asp, line 63

...for this code here:

strUserName=Replace(Request.Form("txtUserName"),"'","''")

Can anyone see something wrong???

Answer (score 11):

What value did you see the `AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed` property to? Remember that this should be specified in *bytes* so you may want to double-check this.  It would probably be worthwhile to open up your metabase file to ensure your script updated the setting accordingly. On IIS6 you can open `metabase.XML` which is located in `c:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv` and find the line `AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed` to double-check this.

`AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed` specifies the maximum number of bytes allowed in the entity body of an ASP request. If a `Content-Length` header is present and specifies an amount of data greater than the value of `AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed`, IIS returns an error response. This property is related in function to `MaxRequestEntityAllowed`, but is specific to an ASP request.

Official documentation in MSDN: [AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed Metabase Property (IIS 6.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525409(v=vs.90))

Comment: I had the exact same problem as the person who asked the question, and this was my problem.  The request was over 200k, and setting the AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed to a higher value resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you've expanded the Request entity is probably because you are posting a file to the server.  However to do that you will either be using a multipart mime type or you have some home grown code consuming the entity body.  In either case the request Form object is not going to be of any use.  It only works when standard url encode form data is posted.