# classic asp Request.Form("ac") is throwing error above 900 lines

Tags: asp-classic

I have an form which on submit goes to tst.asp ,in tst.asp i was using Request.Form("ac") to get the value of an text box from previous page.the text box value is being copied from an text file.and in tst.asp page i am geting the value and writing it to an another .txt file.it is working fine if the no of lines is less than 900.if these lines crosses above 900 then i get the error msg 
"Request object error 'ASP 0104 : 80004005'
Operation not Allowed
/CAPMAdjustments/arpit1.asp, line 8"
line 8 is texttoinsert1 = Request.Form("ac").so can anyone please help me with this issue.below is the code which i wrote.

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<HTML>
<%
FileName = Request.QueryString
Dim FSO
set FSO = server.createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
if FSO.FileExists(FileName) Then
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
Dim file    
set file = FSO.GetFile(FileName)
Response.Write FileName
Dim sScriptLocation, sScriptName, iScriptLength, iLastSlash
set sScriptLocation = Request.QueryString
iLastSlash      = InStrRev(sScriptLocation, "\")
iScriptLength   = Len(sScriptLocation)
sScriptName     = Right(sScriptLocation, iScriptLength - iLastSlash)
fname=Replace(sScriptName, ".txt", " ")
Response.Write fname 
Dim TextStream
Set TextStream = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
%>
<FORM action="tst.asp" id="form1" method=post name="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="ac" id="ac" value="">
<input type="textbox" name="fn" id="fn" value='<%=fname%>'>
<button onclick=abc();>save</button>
<textarea rows="100" cols="230" contenteditable>     
<%  
Do While Not TextStream.AtEndOfStream  
Dim Line
Line = TextStream.readline
Response.write "|" 
Line = Line & vbCRLF
Response.write Line
Loop
%>
</textarea>
</form >
<%
Response.Write "</pre><hr>"
Set TextStream = nothing
Else
End If
Set FSO = nothing
%>
</FONT>
</BODY>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function abc()
{
var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]'),
text1 = contenteditable.textContent;
document.getElementById("ac").value=text1;
alert(text1);
}
</script></HTML>
tst.asp page code is as follows
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%Dim FSO
set FSO = server.createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Dim ts  
Dim a
texttoinsert1 = Request.Form("ac")
fname = Request.Form("fn")
Dim fname, lname, name
lname = "A"
name = Request.Form("fn")+lname
str = Replace(name, " ", "")
set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile("E:\applications\FTP\Archive\"+str+".txt",true)
a=Split(texttoinsert1,"|")
for each x in a
ts.Write x 
next
ts.Close()
Response.Write "YOUR FILE HAS BEEN SAVED SUCCESFULLY WITH NAME:" &str
%>
```

Comment: Plenty of questions already on this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22386054/692942, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31525087/692942, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1849202/692942

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete failure when reaching request.form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310915/complete-failure-when-reaching-request-form)

Answer (score 2):

Its because might your request content is more then limit set in IIS. Try to increase **Maximum Requesting Entity Body Limit**. It need to be set in bytes.

[image]

Comment: It's been answered before in a lot more detail doesn't need another one.